# pip install vapi-client-bindings ; installation failed

Tags: python-3.x

I encountered an issue while trying to install a Python package called . I can't install the package using pip, but when I try again, I received the following error:

codeCopy code
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/7t/h__clx3n4zz863c_9_n40hzm0000gq/T/pip-install-9w78twy1/vapi-client-bindings_ce9281703c324553bed1a307a25f2fc1/LICENSE.txt'
The module I am trying to import is com.vmware.vcenter_client.VM. I am not sure what is causing this error, and I am wondering if you can help me troubleshoot this issue. Thank you.
[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCYUK.png)

Please help me。

pip install vapi-client-bindings
pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: @toyotaSupra It is perfectly OK to call pip directly as the questioner has shown.

Comment: @ OldBoy My mistaken. It should be `py -m pip install vapi-client-bindings  --upgrade`

Comment: The error details suggest that a previous install failed, but did not clean up any temporary files. You should look in the  *Lib/site-packages* folder of your virtual environment tree and remove any related to the project you are trying to install. If that still fails then remove the venv entirely and start with a new one.

Comment: @toyotaSupra As I said, it is not necessary to use the *py -m* prefix. all that is needed is `pip install ... `.

Comment: I solved it, I need to install it vsphere-automation-sdk-python@v8.0.0.1 . I have found a solution on GitHub for this project,
```pip install -- use pep517 git+ https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python @V8.0.0.1 # egg=vSphere Automation SDK```
, and then the vapi client bindings are automatically installed